# Angular Universal: avoid restarting CSS animations at DOM replacement

Tags: javascript, css-animations, angular-universal

We have a web-page that starts with some animation: [coara](https://coara.co)

For performance and SEO reasons we normally pre-render our pagees into a static HTML using Angular Universal.

Problem here: The animation re-starts when the DOM is replaced by the Angular code. Is there a way to avoid this, or to wait with DOM replacement until the animation has finished (and not start it again)?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same issue. 
Nice website btw :)

Comment: @Vingtoft I think in the end we removed this animation.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a fake provider on your `app.module.ts` to know where the component is rendered:

```js
 providers: [
    {
      provide: "isBrowser",
      useValue: true,
    },
  ],
```

and this import on your `app.server.module.ts`

```js
 providers: [
    {
      provide: "isBrowser",
      useValue: false,
    },
  ],
```

Then you can import this "provider" on your component like this:

```js
constructor(@Inject("isBrowser") public enableAnimations: boolean) {}
```

Now you can disable animations when the component is load on server side and add the animation on client side.

Comment: This doesn't solve the following though: Run the animation on the pre-rendered HTML and then not run it again on the client side rendered HTML. Any suggestions for that?